# Phidget SBC compatibility with Windows Embedded

Tags: embedded, system, windows-embedded

I am an IT engineering student and I am currently working on embedded system project and I want to know if Phidget SBC supports Windows Embedded because in the product specifications I found that its default OS is Debian Linux. If it is possible, does Phidget SBC3 run Windows Embedded 8/Windows Embedded 8.1 ? Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming issue, so not a question for SO.  As a commercial product, it would make sense to ask the vendor directly.  Note that *Windows Embedded* is not a single operating system.  Only *Windows Embedded Compact* (formerly Windows CE) runs on ARM targets.  As it ships with Linux, it will certainly be capable of supporting WinCE, but with no display, there may be little point, and with no vendor support, you may be on your own making the port. Also consider Microsoft's licencing costs and development costs. Consider eCOS perhaps if you don't want Linux or need hard real-time.

Comment: You'd do better perhaps if a specific OS is required to look for a board that specifically supports it; eg. [this](http://www.directinsight.co.uk/function/reference-designs.html).    Intel Atom based embedded boards will support x86 versions of Windows.